# DynamicModule with SynchronousInitialization False fails to load in CDF Preview

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, cdf-format

I have the following `DynamicModule` which loads fine in a notebook. When I CDF Player preview it I get an abort message but when I Player Pro preview it evaluates as expected.

What am I missing?  Version 11.0.1

```
DynamicModule[{countries = SortBy[#["Name"] &]@RandomEntity["Country", 30]},
 Manipulate[
  EntityValue[country, prop],
  {{country, First@countries, "Country"}, countries},
  {{prop, "Flag", "Property"}, CanonicalName@EntityProperties["Country"]},
  SynchronousInitialization -> False,
  SynchronousUpdating -> False
  ],
 SynchronousInitialization -> False
 ]
```

Comment: It may be a problem with how the preview procedure is run not with your code. Cache calculations may take some time and can hang the preemptive link. You can always go with `CDFDeploy`.

Comment: @Kuba Yes, it works in the actual CDF.

Comment: You can report this to WRI.

Comment: @Kuba Sure thing.